# How to convert AutomationElement.NativeWindowHandle to IntPtr

Tags: c#, winapi, microsoft-ui-automation

I have an `AutomationElement A` (MS UI Automation), which represents a combo box. I want to select n-th item in that combo box using Windows API call

```
IntPtr ComboBox_SetCurSel(IntPtr hWnd, int index)
```

`A.NativeWindowHandle` contains the handle of the combo box, but in order to pass it to `ComboBox_SetCurSel`, I need to convert it from `int` to `IntPtr`.

How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `IntPtr(int)` constructor.

```
IntPtr WindowHandle = new IntPtr(A.Current.NativeWindowHandle);
```

Comment: The code should be: IntPtr WindowHandle = new IntPtr(A.Current.NativeWindowHandle);

Comment: @David Feel free to correct it, I've never used it, but was going on what the OP said.